# Understanding how `os.path.join` works with `os.path.expanduser`

Tags: python, operating-system

What does this line of code mean

```
datafolder = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Data", "books")
```

Does this line create a folder called datafolder and if it does can I insert files into it and load a file through the line

```
!load getdata.py
```

Answer (score 4):

From the docs:

> **`os.path.expanduser(path)`**
>
> On Unix and Windows, return the argument with
>   an initial component of ~ or ~user replaced by that user‘s home
>   directory.

In Unix, your home directory is represented by a tilde (`~`) sign. Using [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) expands the tilde to the actual path:

```
In [765]: os.path.expanduser("~")
Out[765]: '/Users/Coldspeed'
```

This string, along with `'Data'` and `'books'`, are joined together by `os.path.join` to form a fully qualified path:

```
In [766]: os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), 'Data', 'books')
Out[766]: '/Users/Coldspeed/Data/books'
```

This is a convenient way to specify your home directory without having to hardcode it.

Comment: Now I want to run a file but everytime I do, it says NameError: name'datafolder' does not exist